# upload multiple radgrids to single excel sheet with formatting options

Tags: c#, telerik, export, radgrid

I want to upload 3radgrids to a single excel and that too in same sheet on a button click.

Like one table contents followed by other, and so on.

In between i need to add Headings other than the column headers for the contents, 
Can anyone help me in this regard.

```
Protected void buttonclick(object o,sender s)
{
 RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = (GridExcelExportFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(GridExcelExportFormat), alternateText);
 RadGrid1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = CheckBox1.Checked;
 RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
 RadGrid1.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
 RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add(your 3 grids) inside a dummy parent grid. Name the dummy radgrid as `GridMain` and export `GridMain`

Please look at the following code

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="GridMain" runat="server" Skin="Default" ShowHeader="false" OnNeedDataSource="GridMain_NeedDataSource"
            BorderStyle="None" Width="500px">
            <MasterTableView>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
                        Skin="Vista">
                        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ID" UniqueName="ID" DataField="ID" />
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource"
                        Skin="Vista">
                        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Description" UniqueName="Description" DataField="Description" />
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

There is forum post in telerik site, which talks about this issue.
Check it out [Exporting Multiple Radgrids](http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-multiple-grids-to-same-excel-file)

Note: Simply leave blank in need data source

Comment: Shall i export a datatable directly to excel before binding it to grid

Comment: Yes you can but not with telerik methods

Comment: I'm not talking about telerik controls, asking about alternate methods in .net